# Inserting data into SQL Server from Xamarin.Android App randomly closes DB connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Android app for a school project an have ran across a peculiar problem when trying to store user data in the database. I have created a connection with my Microsoft SQL Server database and it inserts fine until I am inserting a bytearray (I am deploying onto my personal device).

Then sometimes it closes the connection during the Insert and nothing gets inserted. Sometimes it does actually insert. There really is no obvious pattern to why it inserts sometimes and why it doesn't others. I am creating a connection in the UI backend and storing "User sign-up" data along with a signature image from a byte array into a SQL Server table.

Note that this is all done within one activity. Once the user clicks "Sign Up" button then it runs this and then moves to another activity. I know the SQL inserts are able to insert sometimes but a lot of the time I just get the exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Server closed the connection.

Should I not have the connection open/close in the activity? Just out of ideas.

Here is my converting BitMap to Image:

```
        var sig = new SignaturePadView(this);
        sig = FindViewById<SignaturePadView>(Resource.Id.signaturePadView1);
        sig.BackgroundColor=Color.Transparent;
        var signatureImage = sig.GetImage();

        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            signatureImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, memStream);
            bitmapData = memStream.ToArray();
        }
```

I can decode and display the image fine on my app so that is being retrieved alright and bitmapData is used in the Insert.

Here are my insert statements:

```
Database db = new Database();
SqlConnection dbcon = db.con;
dbcon.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert Into dbo.Patrons (firstName, lastName, studentID, dateOfBirth, gender, email, isWaiverSigned, isBlayCertified, isLeadCertified, isSuspended, suspensionReason, dateSuspended, dateUnsuspended, dateOfCreation, lastCheckIn, signature) Values (@firstName, @lastName, @studentID, @dateOfBirth, @gender, @email, @isWaiverSigned, @isBlayCertified, @isLeadCertified, @isSuspended, @suspensionReason, @dateSuspended, @dateUnsuspended, @dateOfCreation, @lastCheckIn, @signatureImage)", db.con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", newPatron.firstName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", newPatron.lastName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", newPatron.studentID);  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", newPatron.dateOfBirth);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", newPatron.gender);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", newPatron.email);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isWaiverSigned",newPatron.isWaiverSigned);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isBlayCertified", newPatron.isBlayCertified);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLeadCertified", newPatron.isLeadCertified);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isSuspended", newPatron.isSuspended);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suspensionReason", newPatron.reasonSuspended);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateSuspended", newPatron.dateSuspended);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateUnsuspended", newPatron.dateUnSuspended);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfCreation", newPatron.dateCreated);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckIn", newPatron.lastCheckIn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signatureImage", bitmapData);

command.Connection = dbcon;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

try
{
    int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.ToString()}");
}

dbcon.close();
```

Comment: You are using android app with SQL Database? what should you do if your project deployed to a real Phone? Are you sure you can do to connect to your SQL DB?

Comment: @reds I have been deploying to my phone. I can connect and on small inserts it works fine. Large inserts it sometimes works and sometimes the DB just closes during it. It isn't really a change in data because when I doesn't work I send the same data multiple times and then sometimes it goes through.

Comment: Good for you, My advice is can you set command timeout to your code.. its a connection properties. Or call connection first before inserting to a new record and check your SQL connection properties Maybe it's closes because it set up only a few minute of times.

Comment: what is the version of your sql server? `image` type is deprecated in newest versions

Comment: directly connecting from a mobile client to a DB server is a *horrible* idea, even for a student project.  Please consider using an intermediate webservices layer.

Comment: I agreed to @Jason.. that's my first Idea but you says you can connect.. it's just a few of chances using directly without any web service.

Comment: @reds I will have to try that again. I am pretty sure earlier I set the timeout to 0 (I know bad idea) just to see if it would help. Connection still closed.

Comment: @Jason I guess I have been told that. Was trying to do it quick and straightforward and I guess I got bit because of that.

Comment: @anatol I have used different types image and varbinary with no change. I am currently looking up my version.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @reds Although this is probably not advisable, I have ran the insert into a loop. The loop keeps trying the insert until an exception is not thrown (inserted fine) or a counter is exceeded. This allows me to insert into the table. After about 4-5 tries, it usually will insert. Does this help diagnose what's going on.

Comment: @Jason please see above

Comment: @anatol please see above